# What do 'skip the line tickets' mean in Italy

Tags: tickets, italy, rome, florence

I've read about many skip the line tickets- but someone told me- they only allow you to skip the ticketing line- not the security line, is this correct?

If so how can you manage to skip long security lines during peak tourist season in sites like Colosseum, Uffizi, Accademia etc? Are guided tours allowed to skip these lines?

Comment: I’d guess that such tickets allow entry through a dedicated entrance and sales are restricted/entry time slots allocated etc so that long security check queues don’t happen. Highly unlikely that they’d enable you to skip the security check itself

Comment: @Traveller: but maybe like airports: you get a dedicated and often empty security line.

Comment: @Traveller Have no intention of skipping security- just a long security line if possible. I heard some tour guides can take you through it quicker or something- just wanted insight on how true that is, and how to find such tickets

Answer (score 10):

> I've read about many skip the line tickets- but someone told me- they only allow you to skip the ticketing line- not the security line, is this correct?

Security is usually mandated by law or by the property owner, a ticket will not get you out of a security screening line

---

Now, to warn you, most of those tickets are **very** unreasonably priced at third-parties as tourist scams or straight out scams (by giving you invalid tickets...)

This applies both online and on the site itself, don't be fooled.

Try to always scavenge the internet for the official venue site (like for the Sistine Chapel, the official site is https://www.museivaticani.va), you'll have a guarentee of the validity of the ticket.

The main issue with the official site is that it is usually where the tickets are sold out the fastest... For some sights, like the Sistine Chapel, the tickets are sold-out months in advance.
If you really want to get a *last-minute* ticket (without guarantee of validity), you can expect to pay from 2x to 5x the official price (there is a 3rd party site that I won't name that is selling *last-minute* tickets at €45 instead of the official price of €17, and this is far from the worst offenders (70-80 € pp. is not unheard of))

This same third party is also trying to sell you the *Rome Tourist Card*, this is also a tourist scam, and you are extremely warned to avoid it.

---

The **only** official tourist pass is the [Roma Pass](https://romapass.it/en/home/), is of course less full of sights but costs way less and also has full public transport (now, you may want to make your calculations to see how worth it, it is for you)

Comment: If you pay by credit card, you can purchase a third party ticket without a concern as you can always do a chargeback if the ticket turns out to be fake.

Comment: @JonathanReez-onstrike: assuming they allow you ("the credit card machine is broken"), or worst they get your credit card number and they buy a lot of stuff. You get back the charge, but you may need to block the card during your holidays, which has own costs. Do not try to fool a scammer: they have more experience (it is enough just an other person did such thing, and all scammer around know and take measures).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I'm referring to *there is a 3rd party site that I won't name that is selling last-minute tickets*. If you buy online, the risk is very low. I wouldn't buy such a ticket from a shady seller in person, yes.

Comment: @JonathanReez-onstrike Sure, and for a sight like this this is not the worse since it's in the middle of the city, but if that was a day trip and you ended up with a fake ticket, that would just ruin everything... You could, but I wouldn't recommend

Comment: You might even find yourself spending a few unpleasant hours while the police question you about where you bought fake tickets and whether you knew they were fake. Not to mention probably needing to cancel the card you used to buy the fake