# What is the official site to buy Rome Colosseum tickets?

Tags: tickets, bookings, italy, museums, rome

I can't seem to figure out what is the official site to Rome Colosseum tickets.

Is it this one ?

https://ecm.coopculture.it/index.php?option=com_snapp&view=event&id=3793660E-5E3F-9172-2F89-016CB3FAD609&catalogid=B79E95CA-090E-FDA8-2364-017448FF0FA0&lang=en

I am confused because I am unable to book tickets for 19th Oct, 2023 (my travel date).

Yet other sites like Viator seems to have them on that date:

https://www.viator.com/tours/Rome/Colosseum-Skip-the-line-ticket-Self-Guided-Tour/d511-48974P7

I am confused.

Any help?

Comment: Please see [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/182584/118049) about *skip the line* tickets... TLDR, don't buy them, the first link is the official, but only seems to put tickets on sale only 30 days before

Comment: @NicolasFormichella The "first link" there is the official site for _the Vatican museums._ The OP's question asks about tickets to see the Colisseum, which is not located in the Vatican.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica The first link in OP's post (coopculture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official website of the Archeological Park of the Colosseum is [http://www.colosseo.it](https://colosseo.it/en/). On the [dedicated ticketing page](https://colosseo.it/en/opening-times-and-tickets/), you will find information on where to purchase tickets. According to this page:

> The purchase of tickets to visit the Parco archeologico del Colosseo is possible exclusively online through this web page and that of the [Official Concessionaire CoopCulture](https://ecm.coopculture.it/index.php?option=com_snapp&view=products&catalogid=ADAE8874-AE4B-55B9-02FB-0167A81C0247&snappTemplate=template3&lang=en).
>
> [INDIVIDUAL TICKETS ARE ALSO SOLD AT THE TICKET OFFICE IN COLOSSEUM SQUARE: READ HERE](https://colosseo.it/en/2023/05/ticket-office-opening-colosseum-square/)
>
> Please do not encourage the illicit resale of admission tickets to the PArCo and it is recommended to purchase them only through the official channels.
>
> In case of difficulties with the online purchase there is a [help desk in Via dei Verbiti](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Via+dei+Verbiti,+00186+Roma+RM/@41.8904007,12.4900536,19z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x132f61b70b7b2079:0x527c695197775609!2sPiazza+del+Colosseo,+00184+Roma+RM!3b1!8m2!3d41.8909432!4d12.4930388!3m4!1s0x132f61b68edcf497:0x14a6d5cb4b8dd798!8m2!3d41.8904007!4d12.4906008).

So, yes it seems that CoopCulture is officially authorised to sell tickets for the Colosseum.

Comment: This site opens why proxy in Neatherlands

https://nl.hideproxy.me/go.php?u=Ai3cm65ZsJgzg2j4yjZ3XGcjPLK7lwTO8gxVHJbQ6qk7oyHizlwueSac4SVabLmhWDg6upWMMX4S68O1qQuVfO1Y&b=29

Comment: @ng.newbie which site? There are 4 links in the post. :)

Comment: http://www.colosseo.it

Comment: @ng.newbie Strange. When I click on the link I don't get the proxy redirect. Are you sure this is not due to your browser setup?

Comment: For me it does not open without the proxy

Comment: @ng.newbie are you based in the Netherlands?

Comment: nopes, I am in Asia