# Can you buy Colosseum tickets on site?

Tags: tickets, bookings, italy, museums, rome

Related to : [What is the official site to buy Rome Colosseum tickets?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/183452/82021)

I will be visiting Rome in October from 19th to 23rd.

Does the **Colosseum** allow vistors to buy tickets on-site ?

That is, can I stand in a line(no matter how long they are) and **get tickets to the Arena and Underground ?**

I ask because [this video](https://youtu.be/Jvr5UDCKysI?t=71) from 11 months ago, **says that you can no longer buy tickets on site.**

Wondering how true that is.

Comment: As well as the official ticket office, there used to be (pre-Covid) a lot of agents near monuments selling quick access, "skip the queues" and similar packages to get entry. Not sure if they're still there but I imagine they are. (You can also stand outside and order tickets on your phone to use that day, if your issue is that you can't book ahead - often works well if there's a long queue for the ticket office.)

Comment: @StuartF Yes just called up the number in coopculture it seems that you are right. There is a ticketing office nearby via which you can purchase tickets.

Comment: Note that the website linked in the other question also states that the ticket office will only sell tickets "while stock lasts". So just because there is a ticket office, doesn't necessarily mean that you will actually get a ticket. Looking at the onlineshop, the next day with available tickets is October 23rd, so I wouldn't count on being able to buy a ticket on site.

Answer (score 1):

Just called up the number listed in CoopCulture.

It seems that there is a ticketing office via which you can buy tickets.

**Don't trust online sources blindly.**

Comment: Isn't this site an online resource?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Why site ? Coopculture ?